# Solicitation for blog posts

Tags: discussion, blog

This is a proposal for solicitation for entries for the WB blog:

Worldbuilding has been home to your questions and answers for a year now.  However, what we don't ever see are the results of these questions, the stories, art, and games that you create. Universe Factory, our blog, is a place to display your work.

We are looking for artwork, videos, story snippets, world descriptions, in short whatever you've created as a result of your interaction with Worldbuilding SE, we would like to see. If you're interested in offering a series of posts, we especially would like to hear from you.

Info about copyright here.

Drop an answer below if you want to get involved; tell us what you'd like to do with a few details. This thread is not for topic *ideas*; it's for telling us if you'd like to write something.

Comment: @HDE226868, edited with answer.

Comment: Let's not start another list of ideas for topics; we have several of those already, many of which I tried to pull together [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2530/28).  Am I correct that you meant *this* post to be more for specific people signing up to write specific things?

Comment: I've made a bit of an edit to clarify some of these comments. Yell if I got it wrong. Also, am I correct that you meant to put some actual copyright information in there instead of "Info about copyright here."?

Comment: @HDE226868 I don't, actually. A centralized place people can get in touch might be a good idea. Also lets people give more detail.

Comment: This isn't a request for topics but rather a proposal for how a request to the broader community could be written.

Comment: What's the difference between this post and http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/medium-blog-contributorsions?lq=1?

Comment: @HDE226868,  this post is my attempt to contribute to the creation of the WB blog. People have to be invited somehow and my "question" is the text of that invite.

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm!  Since we already have a post for people to indicate interest, and another (several) for collecting ideas about what to blog about, I think this is a duplicate.  You do point out a gap in the other solicitation post, though; we want both regular and one-shot writers, and maybe that's not clear.  I'll update the Community Wiki post there.

Comment: That's fine. Glad it was useful.